# SQL/Google Data studio query - multiple rows for same id

Tags: sql, data-analysis, reporting, looker-studio

For work I am making a dashboard on google data studio.

to make things simple i have 2 tables that I am joining:
orders -> contains info regarding customer, seller, price, shipping etc.
orders_statuses -> each order has a row for each of its possible status (pending, accpted, delivered, canceled)

to make it simple

ORDERS:

| Order id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000€ |
| 2 | 200€ |

ORDERS STATUSES:

| order status id | order id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | pending |
| 2 | 1 | accepted |
| 3 | 1 | canceled |

since I extract data with a left join on the common column **order id**, for order 1 i get an output like:

| order | price | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000€ | pending |
| 1 | 1000€ | accepted |
| 1 | 1000€ | canceled |

Query:

```
select orders.order_id, orders.price, orders_statuses.status

from orders
left join order_statuses on order.order_id = orders_statuses.order_id
```

Now, when on Data studio I try to output all orders that **have been accepted** but **have not been canceled** sadly I get also order 1.
Since the software reads 3 different lines for order 1, it sees the line

|  1    | 1000€ | accepted|

as a valid request for my filters.

Also when i tried to expand the query with

```
   where orders_statuses.status != "canceled"
```

1. i loose the information regarding how many cancels
2. i still get the line of order 1 accepted

I (think I) need some way to have the status information of each status **on the same row** of my query or any other smarter way to filter the information.

Thank you for the help

---

full query just to be clear, even though I doubt it helps:

```
select 
o.id as order_id, 
u_s.email as seller_email,
u_s.nation as seller_nation,
u_s.zip as seller_zip,
u_b.email as buyer_email, 
o.shipping_cost_to_platform as shipping_cost, 
o.shipping_fee as shipping_fee,
o.typology,
o.purchase_link_sent_at as quotation_sent,
o.paid_at, 
o_s.status as order_status, 
o_s.completed_at as order_status_update, 
o_s.deleted_at as order_status_deleted,
o.created_at, 
o.delivered_at, 
o.estimated_delivery_at,
o.tracking_vector,
(o_p.`product_sell_amount` * o_p.`quantity`) as item_sell_price,
o.shipping_method,
Concat(a.city,',',a.nation,a.zip) as full_address,
u_b.nation as user_nation,
a.nation, 
p.period,
c.billing_vat,
c.billing_nation as seller_nation_company,
c.billing_zip as seller_zip_company,
ct.slug_name as category, 
o.quotation_number,
p.id


from orders as o
left join users as u_s on u_s.id = o.seller_user_id
left join users as u_b on u_b.id = o.buyer_user_id
left join orders_statuses as o_s on o_s.order_id = o.id
left join addresses as a on o.ship_to_id = a.id
left join orders_products as o_p on o_p.order_id = o.id
left join products as p on p.id = o_p.product_id
left join companies as c on c.id = u_s.company_id
left join categories as ct on ct.id = p.category_id
```

I tested several different filter types in google data studio, and a few variations on my original query.
I scanned google for help, but to no avail.